# Rails nested resourceful form_for how to match create route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, form-for

I'm on Ruby-on-rails 5.2.4.2 Ruby 2.4.1

I have these nested resource routes:

```
resources :groups do
  resources :group_sessions, except: [:show]
end
```

I'm trying to share a form to create and edit group sessions:

```
= form_for [@group, @group_session] do |f|
```

New action in group_sessions controller:

```
def new
  @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
  @group_session = @group.group_sessions.build
end
```

Edit works fine but when I load the new form here http://0.0.0.0:3000/groups/1/group_sessions/new I get the error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"group_sessions", :group_id=>"1", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

Obviously the group_session id isn't set because it's just been built and hasn't been saved. Why does the form not pick the correct route (action: "create" in this case)?

Comment: Can you please post the `edit` and the `update` action?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and inspect `@group_session.new_record?` if its returning false there is something really screwy with your model which is causing it to act as if it was persisted.

Comment: It could also be a simple slop error like for example that `@group_session` is being reassigned in a callback. When you hear hoofbeats...

Comment: @group_session.new_record? returned true @max. It still points to a GroupSession instance so don't think it's being reassigned

Comment: Hmm, thats strange. `form_for` passes the arguments to the polymorphic route helpers which determine the route and method, barring any monkeypatches it should use POST and the collection route for a new record. As this is very unexpected behavior you might need to start taking it apart and isolating it to find the bug, so the starting place is a MCVE that replicates the behavior.

Comment: Thanks @Max I wasn't able to reproduce this in a MCVE which led me to commenting out chunks of code to find what was causing it. Turns out it wasn't the form_for at all. I had a link further down the page that was the issue. Frustratingly the debugger didn't point to the view code but stopped at the controller call to render that view so I had to guess where the problem was.